# Why am I getting undefined getting data from my json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs file I stringified my json result

```
console.log("details... "+JSON.stringify(response));
```

it is somewhat of this nature

```
{"data":{"success":true,"errorCode":0,"data":[{"id":1098,"surname":"Tony","firstname":"Wilson","othername":"","dob":"Jun 9, 2000 12:00:00 AM","gender":"MALE",
```

when I try to console for firstname I get a surprising outcome of undefined

```
console.log("firstname... "+ response.data.data.firstname) ;
```

please what could be wrong

Comment: Use `response.data.data[0].firstname` as `response.data.data` is an array.

Comment: your data response is an array (_for no reason?_), try `response.data.data[0].firstname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response.data.data` is an array, that's what the square brackets are `[]`. You must first access the item itself before accessing the `firstname` attribute on that item.

For example, to get the first item, you would do

```
console.log(response.data.data[0].firstname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
console.log("firstname... "+ response.data.data.firstname) ;
```

Do:

```
console.log("firstname... "+ response.data.data[0].firstname) ;
```

This happens because `firstname` is a key to an object which is inside an array named `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Your final `data` is an array. You have to specify index on that:

```js
var response = {"data":{"success":true,"errorCode":0,"data":[{"id":1098,"surname":"Tony","firstname":"Wilson","othername":"","dob":"Jun 9, 2000 12:00:00 AM","gender":"MALE"}]}};
console.log("firstname... "+ response.data.data[0].firstname)
```